# How to execute tests that match a regular expression only?

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt 0.10.1, I frequently use `test-only` to narrow down the number of my tests.

```
sbt> test-only com.example.MySpec
```

However, I want to narrow down such that I only run tests whose name/description matches a regular expression. Is there some syntax to achieve something like this?

```
sbt> test-only .*someRexExp.*
```

Comment: In case there is not (I doubt it, if it does not work), this should be a feature request in SBT's bugtracker, not here.

Comment: I can only suggest to edit your project file, because that accepts regex.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Full regular expressions are not supported by `testOnly`.  Wildcards are supported, however.

```
sbt> testOnly com.example.*Spec
```

Only the asterisk `*` is interpreted specially here and not the periods.  This will select all tests beginning with `com.example.` and ending with `Spec`.

Or just all test `Spec`s:

```
sbt> testOnly *Spec
```

`testOnly` and other testing information is documented here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing

Answer (score 15):

You can match on test *cases* by their name (instead of or in addition to suite class names) by using [framework-specific runner arguments](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Test+Framework+Arguments). ScalaTest [supports a substring match](http://scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner) with the `-z` argument:

```
> testOnly -- -z insert
> testOnly *TreeSpec -- -z insert
```

This runs all tests with "insert" in their name, then only the matching cases within suites ending in `TreeSpec`, as you would intuit. You can also use `-n TagName` and `-l TagName` to include or exclude, respectively, tags from ScalaTest's tagging support, and `-t` to match an exact test name.

Specs2 [supports full Java regular expressions](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Command+line) with an `-ex` argument:

```
> testOnly -- -ex ".*someRexExp.*"
```

`-include` and `-exclude` support Spec2's tagging features.

See the inline links for full lists of arguments that the runners support. These appear to only work with the `testOnly` sbt command and not `test`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, if you want this without entering sbt first, you have to properly quote the args after sbt: `sbt "testOnly -- -z insert"`

Comment: Not sure when things changed but for some reason with specs2 I now have to use just `ex` with no dash.