# How do you run only a single Spec2 specification with SBT?

Tags: scala, specs2

If you have 2 tests defined in your SBT project:

```
class Spec1 extends Specification {
  def is =
    "Tests for specification 1" ^
      p ^
      "Test case 1" ! todo ^
      end
}
```

and

```
class Spec2 extends Specification {
  def is =
    "Tests for specification 2" ^
      p ^
      "Test case 2" ! todo ^
      end
}
```

Then running `test` from inside SBT will execute both these tests. What is the simplest way to run only one of these tests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `test-only` sbt command.

```
sbt> test-only com.example.MySpec
```

You can even use a wildcard to run a range of tests.
See [How to execute tests that match a regular expression only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997730/in-sbt-can-i-run-only-tests-that-match-a-regular-expression)

Comment: If you don't want to enter the `sbt` shell first, the executable expects only a single argument, so you'll have to pass the whole command in quotes.  Here, `sbt "test-only com.example.MySpec"` or  `sbt "test-only *MySpec"`